# Descargar archivo Excel de forma local a través de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

La duda es la siguiente, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que un usuario al pulsar un botón pueda descargar un fichero '.xlsx' de forma local a través de JavaScript?

En mi aplicación tengo una tabla dónde uso cierto filtros que son gestionados por el servidor a través de PHP mediante una llamada AJAX, una vez creado el fichero excel desde el servidor devuelve TRUE a la petición. En ese momento, se ha creado un excel en un carpeta del servidor, y quiero que al volver si la petición AJAX ha resultado satisfactoria (success) ejecute un código que descargue de forma local un arhcivo excel a través de un ruta especifica.

Es decir, el archivo excel esta creado en el servidor y quiero que se decargue de forma local en lado del cliente.

Comment: El cliente DEBE usar un enlace para descargar dicho documento, automáticamente no lo va a hacer por seguridad.

Comment: @ArnauCastellví El archivo excel no se crea hasta que se realizan los filtros a través de php.

Comment: Una vez generado, envía el enlace en la respuesta del AJAX.

Comment: @ArnauCastellví ¿puedes facilitarme el código de como descargar un fichero xlsx ubicado en un ruta del servidor (localhost)?

Comment: En frio no sabría decirte, pero si el documento se genera en una ruta accesible por el cliente, simplemente envía el enlace, que el cliente incluya la ruta en un enlace de descarga,  y que el servidor elimine el documento en un tiempo prudencial.
Si muestras la parte del código que realiza la ultima petición de AJAX del cliente y como lo soluciona el PHP, seria más fácil.

Comment: Actualmente puedes descargar un archivo desde el servidor directamente en tu petición usando la [API Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Revisa la documentación, hay ejemplos también con archivos.

Comment: ¿Por qué no simplemente rediriges el navegador a la ruta del archivo?

Comment: Puedes al generar el archivo guardar el archivo en una ruta del servidor y responderle al cliente la ruta, y en el lado del cliente creas un <a href=""> con la ruta.  En caso si quieres que hacer que se descargue es tan simple que solo necesitas ponerle un atributo download. Ejemplo: <a href="ruta" download>Descargar</a> y si quieres nombrarla seria <a href="ruta" download="nombre_del_archivo_al_descargar">Descargar</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre la solución gracias a este enlace: [forzar descarga archivo php](https://parzibyte.me/blog/2019/02/06/forzar-descarga-archivo-php-readfile/)

Una vez creado el fichero excel con los filtros seleccionados, ejecuto este código en el mismo php que crea el fichero excel y comprueba a través de un while si ha sido creado:

```
$path_xlsx = '/ruta/fichero.xlsx';

# Comprobamos si ha sido creado el fihcero Excel
while (is_file($path_xlsx) != true) {
    sleep(1);
}

# Forzamos la descarga
$nombreArchivo = basename($path_xlsx);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path_xlsx));
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$nombreArchivo");
readfile($path_xlsx);
```